# I have custom TypeAdapterFactory which crash in empty list

Tags: java, android

```
public class SignInResponse {

@SerializedName("Status")
private String status;
@SerializedName("personID")
public long personID;
@SerializedName("UserInfo")
public SignInResponseUser userInfo;
@SerializedName("Types")
public ArrayList<SignInResponseTypes> TYpes;
}
```

When take the response if (Types) which is Array List is empty the app crash. I can handle the response in the (return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement), when empty array list comes;

My Custom adapter:

```
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

    final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
    final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

        public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
            delegate.write(out, value);
        }

        public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
            if (!jsonElement.isJsonNull() && (jsonElement.isJsonObject())) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                if (jsonObject.has("Types") && (jsonObject.get("Types").isJsonArray())) {
                    JsonArray jsonTypeArray = jsonObject.get("Types").getAsJsonArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonTypeArray.size(); i++) {
                        JsonObject jsonType = jsonTypeArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        for (int t = 0; t < jsonType.size(); t++) {
                            if (jsonType.has("Type")) {
                                String annotationValue = jsonType.get("Type").getAsString();
                                String[] splitTypeName = annotationValue.split("\\|");
                                jsonType.addProperty("enterName", splitTypeName[0]);
                                jsonType.addProperty("typeName", splitTypeName[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                jsonElement = jsonObject;
            }
            return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
        }
    }.nullSafe();
}
```

crashReport:
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                                  Process: org..., PID: 20561
                                                                                  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at path $
                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
                                                                                      at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(TypeAdapter.java:285)
                                                                                      at com..model.user.repository.network.response.deserialize.SignInTypeAdapter$1.read(SignInTypeAdapter.java:48)
                                                                                      at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1.read(TypeAdapter.java:199)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)

The response which crash :

{"Types":"","UserInfo":"","Status":2002}

the Types is empty the response wait for array list in that field(Types)

ANY SOLUTION;

Comment: Post your crash log

Comment: Whenever asked question. please consider posting Logs to make other users know your problem easier.